# Test Class is not working for Map in class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I am not able to get coverage for the Maps in the class. I only getting 54% coverage and don't know what else to try. Can anyone please help me here.  I will truly appreciate it!

```
public with sharing class SODetailsCountsONProducts {


public  void Run(SO_Detail__c[] items){


Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();

for(SO_Detail__c prodItem : items){
    if(!String.isEmpty(prodItem.NRProducts__c)){
        productIds.add(prodItem.NRProducts__c);
    }

}


Map<Id, Decimal> Total_Items_Resolved_Map= new Map<Id, Decimal>();
Map<Id, Decimal> SO_Detail_Ordered_Map = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
Map<Id, Decimal> SO_Detail_Received_Map= new Map<Id, Decimal>();
Map<Id, Decimal> SO_Detail_Shipped_Map= new Map<Id, Decimal>();


for(AggregateResult result :  [SELECT NRProducts__c p, SUM(Total_Resolved__c) resolved, SUM(Qty__c) qty, SUM(Total_Received_by_Amazon__c) received, SUM(Total_Shipped__c) shipped
                                 FROM SO_Detail__c
                                 WHERE Buyer_Approved__c != NULL AND NRProducts__c IN : productIds 
                                 GROUP BY NRProducts__c]){   

//This section doesn't get coverage  
   Total_Items_Resolved_Map.put((Id)result.get('p'),Double.valueof(result.get('resolved'))); 
      SO_Detail_Ordered_Map.put((Id)result.get('p'),Double.valueof(result.get('qty')));
      SO_Detail_Received_Map.put((Id)result.get('p'),Double.valueof(result.get('received'))); 
      SO_Detail_Shipped_Map.put((Id)result.get('p'),Double.valueof(result.get('shipped')));  
}


List<NRProducts__c> products = [SELECT Id FROM NRProducts__c WHERE Id IN :productIds];

for(NRProducts__c p : products ){


    p.Total_Items_Resolved__c= Total_Items_Resolved_Map.get(p.Id); 
    p.SO_Detail_Ordered__c = SO_Detail_Ordered_Map .get(p.Id);
    p.SO_Detail_Received__c = SO_Detail_Received_Map.get(p.Id);
    p.SO_Detail_Shipped__c = SO_Detail_Shipped_Map.get(p.Id);
}

update products ;
```

}

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class tst_SODetailsCountsONProducts {

static testMethod void tst_SODetailsCountsONProducts () {

List<Purchase_Order_Details__c > invAdj = new List<Purchase_Order_Details__c >();

 Account account1 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1');
    insert account1;

 NRProducts__c product = new NRProducts__c(Account__c = account1.Id, Name = '105823437',Total_Items_Resolved__c = null,SO_Detail_Ordered__c = null,SO_Detail_Received__c = null,SO_Detail_Shipped__c = null   );
    insert product;

 Entity__c ent = new Entity__c(name='Carlos') ;
    insert new Entity__c []{ent}; 

 Outbound_Sales_Order__c oso = new Outbound_Sales_Order__c(
    Entity__c= ent.id

    );
    insert oso;   


 SO_Detail__c osoDetail = new SO_Detail__c(
         Outbound_Sales_Order__c = oso.id,
         NRProducts__c = product.id,
         Qty__c =10  

         );


 Test.startTest();

     insert  osoDetail;
     update osoDetail;
     delete osoDetail;

 Test.stopTest();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buyer_Approved__c appears to be null in your test data and therefore the aggregate query in your code isn't returning any results, so the maps aren't getting populated. Set Buyer_Approved__c on your SO_Detail__c in your test record so that the aggregate SOQL returns results.

Comment: greenstork, thank you for your help! that made the magic.